# WSO2 Identity Server 4.6 Cluster OAuth validation issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have an Identity Server cluster environment with two nodes.  It was working without any issue for a long time but last few days OAuth2 validation failing for few users. Two OAuth tokens generated within few seconds and calls are executing with the invalid token (first token). So all the calls failing with "Invalid Access Token or Client Id" error. We have also rebooted Identity Server still same behavior. Token validation is working if one node is removed from the cluster. It will continue to work till next token generation. I am thinking it could be the issue with some cache in Identity Server. Is there a way to clear cache in Identity Server.

Sorry for the lengthy post...

Answer (score 0):

Caches are cleared when you restart nodes, so I don't think this is a caching issue.

I can't say a reason for sure either, but I suspect the clocks of these nodes. Are you sure both servers' clocks are synced? I believe this can happen if the token validation node has a different time than the token generated node.

Just a thought. Make sure falling back from daylight saving time didn't affect just one node in a different way.

Comment: I verified both nodes having the same clock time.